# Python3 - while ids > Stop: TypeError: unorderable types: str()> int()

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, error-handling, while-loop

Hello I am trying to run a program that will return back students grades and their average. ALSO I KNOW I AM A BASIC BRAINLESS FIRST YEAR PROGRAMMER. I WILL PROBABLY BE HORRIBLE AT PROBABLY. HOWEVER PLEASE HELP THE BEST YOU CAN IT WOULD BE GREATLY APPRECIATED.
THANK YOU.

The error says to be in line 49.

saying that"

```
line 49, in <module>
 while ids > STOP:
TypeErrorL unorderable types: str() > int()
```

XXXX

```
 def assigngrades(scores):
     avg = sum(scores)/len(scores)
     print(avg)


     for val in scores:
      if val > avg + 10:
       grade = 'A'
      elif val > avg + 5:
       grade = 'B'
      elif val > avg -5:
        grade = 'C'
      elif val > avg - 10:
       grade = 'D'
      else:
       grade = 'F'
      grades.append(grade)
     print("in assigngrades, grades: ",grades)
     return grades



    def printsummary(grades, ave):
     print('ID        Score        Average        Grade')
     print('===========================================')
     print( )


     for val in range(len(ids)):
      print('val', val)
      print(ids,' ',scores, ' ', grades)
     return

    #main
    ids = []
    scores = []
    grades = []
    STOP = 0


    ids = input("Enter an ID:")
    while ids > STOP:
     ids.append(ids)
     score = eval(input("Enter a score:"))
     scores.append(score)
     id = (input("Enter an ID number, 0 to STOP:"))

     grades = assigngrades(scores)
     print("after while loop")
     print("Ids:", ids, "Scores:", scores, "Grades:", grades)
     printsummary(grades, avg)
```

Nonetheless, I am confused on what is the issue.I appreciate your time and help looking at this. Thank you so so so much. Yes I know I am stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input()` function returns a string, so you should convert it to an integer with `int()` so you can compare its value with another integer. You should also name the variable that stores the user input something other than `ids` since you already define it as a list:

```
ids = []
scores = []
grades = []
STOP = 0

id = int(input("Enter an ID:"))
while id > STOP:
    ids.append(id)
    score = eval(input("Enter a score:"))
    scores.append(score)

    grades = assigngrades(scores)
    print("after while loop")
    print("Ids:", ids, "Scores:", scores, "Grades:", grades)
    printsummary(grades, avg)
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you are saying and implemented it. However, its now returning the same error but saying "TYPEERROR: unorderable types: list() > int()"

Comment: I apologize for how redundant this is. And I appreciate your help

Comment: I forgot to edit the `ids` in your `while` condition to `id` after renaming your duplicating variable name. Try it again now.

Comment: Thank you so much it got me further. its now just saying "NameError: name 'avg' is not defined". But I appreciate your help